# Do something after fetch and mounted complete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a simple nuxt.js component like the one below.

`Chart` is a component that has a method which will receive the data that is fetched in `fetch()`.

If I simply call that method after `await fetch('...')` I get an error when it's rendered on client-side since the `Chart` component has not yet been mounted. How could I go about to do something after fetch AND mounted?

And I can't do it in `mounted()` because then I can't be sure that the fetch is complete.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!--Custom component-->
        <Chart ref="chart"/> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                chartData: []
            }
        },
        async fetch() {
            this.chartData = await fetch('https://api.mocki.io/v1/b1e7c87c').then(res =>
                res.json()
            )
            this.$refs.chart.insertSeries(this.chartData) // doesn't work because Chart is not mounted yet.
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Which chart provider are you using?  Is Chart a 3rd party component?

Comment: Yes, I'm using HighCharts. But Chart is a wrapper that I've made myself around it. So it's more of a general question on how I can call any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of handling this situation would be to use a prop so that `<Chart>` can handle the data itself, and watch the prop in the child.

*Parent*

```html
<Chart :chart-data="chartData" />
```

*Chart*

```
export default {
  props: ['chartData'],
  watch: {
    chartData(newValue) {
      if(newValue.length) {
        this.insertSeries(newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Variation:** You could use `v-if` instead of a `watch`:

*Parent*

```html
<Chart v-if="chartData.length" :chart-data="chartData" />
```

*Chart*

```js
export default {
  props: ['chartData'],
  created() {
    this.insertSeries(this.chartData);  // `chartData` is guaranteed to exist
  }
  ...
}
```

---

**Note:** There is a slight difference that can emerge between these two options.  Imagine you wanted a loading animation while chart data was loading.

With the first option, since the component is shown immediately, the loading functionality would have to be put in the child.  In the second option, it would be put in the parent (in a `v-else`).